# Is there a well known algorithm fill in the grid given a set of points?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I saw this game here [Flow](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/flow/117ec8c4-0dab-4536-9bab-2fbecb9583bb), it looks quite interesting.

> Connect matching colors with pipe to create a flow. Pair all colors,
>   and **cover the entire board** to solve each puzzle. But watch out, pipes
>   will break if they cross or overlap.

Given a set of pairs `(x, y)`, is there an algorithm to solve the puzzle, i.e. fill in the whole grid (assuming there is a solution) that I'm not aware of?

[image]

Comment: Love this game, super addicting.

Comment: I have a feeling it can be solved using [flow networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network)… Don’t know how, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very specific instance of the global routing problem. Global routing is a well studied problem in VLSI CAD (where one needs to route millions of nets in an integrated circuit). The problem is NP-complete and can be solved in many ways depending upon the tradeoff you need between runtime and quality. Following wiki is a good starting point:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_(electronic_design_automation)

Paper here gives a survey of various techniques:

[http://dropzone.tamu.edu/~jhu/publications/HuIntegration01.pdf](http://dropzone.tamu.edu/%7Ejhu/publications/HuIntegration01.pdf)

Bear in mind that the pointers I had given typically try to solve a far more complex version of the problem you had stated. Never-the-less, the mathematical concepts remain the same.

Comment: Please, correct the first hyperlink (Wikipedia). It has a missing parenthesis at the end :)